# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

I have this error in this code how can I solve it?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class yenikayit
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim isimT As String = ""
    Dim soyisimT As String = ""
    Dim tcNoT As String = ""
    Dim yasT As String = ""
    Dim cinsiyetT As String = ""
    Dim perNoT As String = ""
    Dim egDurT As String = ""
    Dim meslekT As String = ""
    Dim telNoT As String = ""
    Dim emailT As String = ""

    isimT = TextBox1.Text
    soyisimT = TextBox2.Text
    tcNoT = TextBox3.Text
    yasT = TextBox6.Text
    cinsiyetT = ComboBox1.Text
    perNoT = TextBox4.Text
    egDurT = ComboBox2.Text
    telNoT = TextBox5.Text
    meslekT = TextBox10.Text
    emailT = TextBox9.Text


    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Personel (isim,soyisim,Yas,Cinsiyet,Alan,Egitim,TC,personel_id,tel_no,email) VALUES(isimT,soyisimT,yasT,cinsiyetT,meslekT,egDurT,tcNoT,perNoT,telNoT,emailT)"
    Dim dbsource As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\AGKS\AGKS\Database5.accdb"
    Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(dbsource)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim sonuc As Boolean
    sonuc = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (sonuc = 1) Then
        MsgBox("Girdiğiniz veriler kayıt olmuştur")
        conn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

[this is the part of the code that give us error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQNhk.png)

Comment: You can't just put variable names in your sql string like that, you have to actually add them to the OleDbCommand's parameters collection

Comment: I'm not expert as you can see. Can you fix it?

Comment: Such things are *easily* researched.  If you goggle your title (new one without the commentary), there are tens of thousands of hits.  Rather than using random code that you hope might work, a little research on the tools and libraries you are using does wonders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, try something like this:

```
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Personel (isim,soyisim,Yas,Cinsiyet,Alan,Egitim,TC,personel_id,tel_no,email) "
query +="VALUES(@isimT,@soyisimT,@yasT,@cinsiyetT,@meslekT,@egDurT,@tcNoT,@perNoT,@telNoT,@emailT)"
Dim dbsource As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\AGKS\AGKS\Database5.accdb"
Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(dbsource)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
 query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isimT", TextBox1.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soyisimT", TextBox2.Text)   
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tcNoT", TextBox3.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yasT", TextBox6.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cinsiyetT", ComboBox1.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@perNoT", TextBox4.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@egDurT", ComboBox2.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telNoT", TextBox5.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meslekT", TextBox10.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailT", TextBox9.Text)
 conn.Open()
 Dim sonuc As Boolean
    sonuc = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (sonuc = 1) Then
        MsgBox("Girdiğiniz veriler kayıt olmuştur")
        conn.Close()
    End If
```

This should do the job. This should fix your exception.

Comment: OleDB doesn't actually use the parameter name.  The parameters have to be in the same order as they appear in the query.  Your parameters are not in the proper order.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code does not add any parameter values to the command, hence the "No Values Given" error. The command doesn't recognize those names and assign them values just because you have declared them as variables above. You should make it clear that those are parameters in your sql query, and then set each parameter's value before executing the query:

> Note that all instances of `OleDbType.VarChar` need to be replaced with the correct datatypes of your columns. I obviously have no way of knowing what types those columns are so I have just made them all VarChar, but you should adjust those to match your table schema.

```
Dim dbsource As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\MONSTER\Desktop\AGKS\AGKS\Database5.accdb"
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Personel (isim,soyisim,Yas,Cinsiyet,Alan,Egitim,TC,personel_id,tel_no,email) " & _
                       "VALUES (@isimT,@soyisimT,@yasT,@cinsiyetT,@meslekT,@egDurT,@tcNoT,@perNoT,@telNoT,@emailT)"
Using conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(dbsource)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
    With cmd
        .Parameters.Add("@isimT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@soyisimT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@yasT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox6.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@cinsiyetT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@meslekT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox10.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@egDurT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox2.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@tcNoT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@perNoT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@telNoT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@emailT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox9.Text
    End With
    conn.Open()
    Dim sonuc As Boolean
    sonuc = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (sonuc = 1) Then
        MsgBox("Girdiğiniz veriler kayıt olmuştur")
    End If
    conn.Close()
End Using
```